# looping through list of file names and reading cannot find file name

Tags: python

I've created list of files using

```
import os
csvs = sorted(os.listdir("distribution_csvs"))
print(csvs)

>>> ["file1.csv", "file2.csv", etc...]
```

So I am trying to loop through them

```
for csv in csvs:
    df         = pd.read_csv(csv, parse_dates=["gps_updated_at"], index_col="gps_updated_at")
    date       = csv.split(".")[0]
    df_by_date = df[date]
    df_6pm     = df_by_date.between_time("18:00", "18:03")
    print(df_6pm.value_counts())
```

which is giving me

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'2019-09-26.csv' does not exist: b'2019-09-26.csv'`

I believe because it is not properly giving csv as 'file1.csv'

however when I print csv and print(type(csv)) it prints the right name and give string type.

Sorry, I simply didn't add full path....

I've solved it by doing

**ANSWER**

```
for csv in csvs:
    df         = pd.read_csv("file_path/"+ csv, parse_dates=["gps_updated_at"], index_col="gps_updated_at")
    date       = csv.split(".")[0]
    df_by_date = df[date]
    df_6pm     = df_by_date.between_time("18:00", "18:03")
    print(df_6pm.value_counts())
```

Comment: os.listdir gives just the file names and not the complete path. The list directory may not be same as current working directory.

Comment: oh!!! omg haha thanks!!